# Laravel Query builder and table names

Tags: laravel, database-table, laravel-query-builder

I noticed that I write the database table names quite a lot, and in different files, when I use the Query Builder. If I were to change the database table names, I would have to search and change quite many rows in my project.
Is this an issue your Laravel guys noticed and come up with an solution to?

I like the Eloquent approach which uses class models, instead of database names; but for some queries I think the Query Builder is a better solution (though I am no expert in this matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using OOP concept. Laravel is a framework, so no one stops you from using basic PHP OOP concept. This is what I do:

Consider my query is like :

```
$result=DB::table('myTable')->select()->get();
```

What I do is make a class that holds all the tablenames :

```
class TableName
{
    private $tableName= "myTable";
    public function getTableName()
    {
        return $this->tableName;
    }

    public function setTableName($table_name)
    {
        $this->tableName = $table_name;
    }
}
```

Now all i have to do is call a method using an object in the file I want to use the table like :

```
$name = new TableName() ;
$result=DB::table($name->getTableName())->select()->get();
```

Use wherever you want. I don't think its the best solution however it works for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 14):

If you already have a queryBuilder object you can obtain the table name like

`$tableName = $query->getModel()->getTable();`

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. It allows you get current target table of query builder wherever in code, which is very useful.

Answer (score 9):

Use this in your query :

```
(new YourModel())->getTable()
```

Example :

```
DB:raw('SELECT * FROM '.(new User())->getTable().' WHERE id=3');
```

Comment: Interesting. Could this be done without using the raw?

Comment: Yes this code just get the table name, you can use it evrywhere, it's easier than adding more code I think that this is a better solution than the other answer.

Comment: there are times when you don't have a model. e.g if you have a system already built(e.g magento). Now you want to use its database, you cannot make a model of that as the table doesn't come in your way, you only have to select it. But for a normal model your solution is perfect +1 to you

Comment: Thanks. If I could I would mark both as the right answer. I am not sure how to handle when a question can have multiple right answers, here on stackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extend the model class.

```
CModel extend Model {

   protected static $tableName;

   public static getTableName(){
       if(static::$tableName)
          return static::$tableName;

       /* if you create a "reference break" you don't have to *
       /* create "protected static $tableName" row in your all model */

       $table = (new static())->getTable();
       return static::$tableName = &$table;
   }
}

YourModel extends CModel {...}
```

than you can use

```
YourModel::getTableName()
```

I'm not have better idea.